# htaccess cannot load correct content

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have 2 websites: one site that located in the root of the public html folder and another site located in WFM subfolder, the WFM subfolder is facing some problem which is unable to redirect to the correct page that instead of displaying the contents in **domain.com.sg/careers**, it is reloading the **home page** instead.

The strange part is the images, JS and CSS return 200 OK although the files contains the content of index.php. Tested through Google Chrome web developer tools.

domain.com.sg is just a dummy url.

Code on /home/webfire/public_html/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
IndexIgnore *
Options All -Indexes
IndexOptions +SuppressHTMLPreamble

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com.sg  #Not working correctly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wfm   #Not working correctly
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wfm/$1 [L]      #Not working correctly

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  #For website located in the public_html folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  #For website located in the public_html folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1/ [L] #For website located in the public_html folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^PUT$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^MOVE$
RewriteRule ^/files/(.*)\.php /files/$1.nophp



RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com.sg/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com.sg$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.com.sg/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.com.sg$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
IndexIgnore *
Options All -Indexes
IndexOptions +SuppressHTMLPreamble

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# existing rule to block images hot linking 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com.sg/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com.sg$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.com.sg/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.com.sg$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]

# for subdomain forward to /wfm/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com\.sg$
RewriteRule ^((?!wfm/).*)$ /wfm/$1 [L,NC]

# existing rule to handle PUT/MOVE reqquest
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^PUT$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^MOVE$
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)\.php /files/$1.nophp [L]

# is PHP file exists for given URI then use it
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

# forward rest to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: That's great! Would you mind to add comment for each lines for I see new syntax that is new to me.

Comment: Added comments before each rule now.